# Assigning value to a specific bit in 2D unpacked array[system-verilog]

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to assign value on a specific bit of a 2D array(code[i][k]). This is a net type. But the value not being assigned.reg [3:0] code[0:3] gets unknown logic value 'X'.

Here is the code snippet

```
            for(k=0;k<len;k++) begin
                if (tc[k] == 1'b0) begin
                    code[i][k]= 1'b0;//----> value is not assigning as expected
                end else begin
                    code[i][k]= 1'b1;// ---> value is not assigning as expected
                end
            end
            codeLen[i] = len;
```

This for loop belongs to *always* block.Here, *code* and *codeLen* is output type.

```
output [3:0] code[0:3]; 
output [3:0] codeLen[0:3];
reg [3:0] code[0:3]; 
reg [3:0] codeLen[0:3];
```

*codeLen[i]* is assigned correctly but not the *code[i][k]*. I was trying to assign k-th bit of i-th byte.

Details
I have created a module which takes 6 inputs and returns two 2-dimensional arrays as output.

Here is the module:

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
module generate_code(CLK,nRST,nodes,nodeCount,characters,charCount,code,codeLen);
input CLK;
input nRST;
input integer nodeCount;//Total nodes in huffman tree
input integer charCount;//Total unique characters
input [6:0] characters[0:3];
input [23:0] nodes[0:6]; // total characters

output [3:0] code[0:3]; //[2:0] max code length <= total characters
output [3:0] codeLen[0:3];

reg [3:0] code[0:3];
reg [3:0] codeLen[0:3];

reg[3:0] tc;//temprary code reg. Holds a single bit in each byte
integer len=0;//code length
reg [23:0] tNode;

function void FindRoot;
    reg [23:0] aNode;//local
    integer i;
    begin
    for (i=0; i<nodeCount;i++) begin // For all nodes
        aNode= nodes[i]; // aNode is current node
        if (tNode[23:16] == aNode[14:7]) begin
            tc[len]= tNode[15];//15th bit of nodes is codebit
            len++;
        //aNode is parent of tNode. Is it root?
            if(aNode[23:16]==8'b0000_0000) begin//or frequency==nodeCount or node_id = 8'b1111_1111
                return;
            end else begin
                tNode=aNode;
                FindRoot();
            end
        end
    end
    end
endfunction

always@(posedge CLK or negedge nRST)
begin
    if(!nRST) begin
    // init
    end 
    else begin 
        // Do code generation
        integer i,j,k;
        for(i= 0;i < charCount;i++) begin // For all character we are going to find codeword
            for(j=0; j<nodeCount; j++) begin
                tNode= nodes[j];//current node
                if (characters[i] == tNode[6:0]) begin
                // Got the character. tNode is a leaf nodes. Lets back track to root.
                    break;
                end
            end
            len=0;
            FindRoot();
            for(k=0;k<len;k++) begin
                if (tc[k] == 1'b0) begin
                    code[i][k]= 1'b0;
                end else begin
                    code[i][k]= 1'b1;
                end
            end
            //code[i]=2;
            codeLen[i]= len;
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

When I am assigning values to code[][], it is expected that following loop is executed. Though not all the bits of code[][] will be set. During debugging, when I come to assignment, I found that value is not being assigned (code[i][k] =1 or 0). Its getting unknown logic value X.

```
                for(k=0;k<len;k++) begin
                if (tc[k] == 1'b0) begin
                    code[i][k]= 1'b0;
                end else begin
                    code[i][k]= 1'b1;
                end
            end
```

Testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module generate_code_test;

// Inputs
reg CLK;
reg nRST;
integer nodeCount=7;//Total nodes in huffman tree
integer charCount=4;//Total unique characters
reg [6:0] characters[0:3];
reg [23:0] nodes[0:6]; // total characters

// Outputs
wire [3:0] code[0:3]; //[2:0] max code length <= total characters
wire [3:0] codeLen[0:3];

generate_code uut (
    .CLK(CLK), 
    .nRST(nRST), 
    .nodes(nodes), 
    .nodeCount(nodeCount), 
    .characters(characters), 
    .charCount(charCount), 
    .code(code), 
    .codeLen(codeLen)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    CLK = 0;
    nRST = 0;
    nodeCount= 7;
    charCount= 4;
    characters[0]= 7'b110_0001;
    characters[1]= 7'b110_0010;
    characters[2]= 7'b110_0011;
    characters[3]= 7'b110_0100;

    nodes[0] = 24'b0000_0011_0_0000_0001_110_0001;
    nodes[1] = 24'b0000_0011_1_0000_0010_110_0011;
    nodes[2] = 24'b0000_0101_1_0000_0011_111_1111;
    nodes[3] = 24'b0000_0101_0_0000_0100_110_0010;
    nodes[4] = 24'b1111_1111_1_0000_0101_111_1111;
    nodes[5] = 24'b1111_1111_0_0000_0110_110_0100;
    nodes[6] = 24'b0000_0000_0_1111_1111_111_1111;

    // Wait 10 ns for global reset to finish
    #10;
    nRST = 1;

end
parameter DELAY = 1;
always
    #DELAY CLK = ~CLK; 

endmodule
```

The code has been compiled in ModelSim 2016
I just started learning verilog. So I would really appreciate your help to show my mistakes.
Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect the behaviour is caused by code you have not posted. For example, what are `k` and `len` - could it be your loop is being executed zero times? Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - some small block of compilable code - so that someone else can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor, Thank you for the response. I have uploaded compilable module along with testbench. I believe, loop is executed when I assign the bit of code[][]. k and len should have necessary values at that time. Though I am not setting all the bits of code[][]. When I debug the module and come to that assignment, I found line is executed but code[][] is not assigned.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile - see [http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4uk4](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4uk4). I fixed it and then the simulation didn't stop. Can you (a) make it compile (the "C" in MCVE) and (b) take some of the extra stuff out leaving just the problem (the "M" in MCVE)?

Comment: my guess is that you have an issue with `len` calculation and using the static function. can you **verify** that `len` is not zero? How do you debug it? And, btw, stop using this coding style from 90s. System verilog allows you to return values from functions, use automatic function.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor, I really appreciate your effort. register declaration got missing during copy/paste the module generate_code. However I was able to find a fix. Regards.

Comment: @Serge,  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Serge,  1. len should not be zero when value is assigned to code[][]. Logic and input ensures that. 2. Debugged using Modelsim. 3. I agreed. I just started learning and I don't know lots of thing. Code is not in good shape, there is redundancy. I am in a bit rush to complete a project using verilog which I don't have any kind of experience previously :(

Comment: @rakibdana there is no obvious reason to assume that 'len' value is non-zero in this code example. You need to trace the values of the inputs and the signals either by using a waive tracer or at least by adding `$display` to print values.

Answer (score 0):

I got a fix for my problem. Not all the bits of code[][] has been set. This leads to unknown logic value in code[][] even after setting the bit. It gets solved after initializing all the bits of code[][] in *always* block.